# embed google / microsoft excel spreadsheet

Tags: web-services, excel, embed, google-sheets

I want to embed a Microsoft Excel or Google Docs spreadsheet or a web app, plugin which I can use to create a spreadsheet with the same Excel functionality in to a website.

I've looked few hours for some ways to do this but it seems that with all of them is possible 
just to embed them not editing.

Basically, what I need is to be able to publish a spreadsheet on my website but with the option to edit  it directly from my website.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Google spreadsheet and share it. From the spreadsheet menu: File->Share under "who has access" click the "Change" link. Then you can select "Public ..." or "Anyone with a link".
And then select the option so that people can edit it.